# Search for a Key in an Array in which consecutive numbers differ by +1/-1

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a one-dimensional array. Each number of this array differs from the pervious number by +1 or -1. Example: Array {5,6,7,6,5,6,7,8,9,8}

You are given a number to search its first occurrence in this array (example: search for 8 -- Your code should return 7). Do not use Linear Search.

Without Linear Search, I could have tried it as follows:

```
Check if (array[0] == Key)
{
        YES:
           return 0;
}

Take a variable: Diff = array[0]

// Keep on traversing the array, if Next Number>Current Number
   Diff += 1
   Else
   Diff -= 1

if (Diff==key)
{
    return current_index+1;
}
```

But this method is too generic. Even if the difference between the keys is NOT +-1 but something else, this method will solve this problem.

What is so specific about +-1 difference, which can give me a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're describing as a "too generic" method is still a linear scan of the array. Zim-Zam's anwer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sounds like a homework, so I'll just give a hint. If array[a] is less than your key and array[b] is greater than your key, what have you discovered? Now to complete the solution, use whichever you like of recursion or looping (because those two things are equivalent).

Note that this answer is different from Zim-Zam's.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Sorry I missed it, Corrected Formatting.

Comment: @minopret: No, its not homework.

Comment: @SandeepSingh Don't pick too quickly, you can do much better than the selected answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say you're searching for 16, and array[0] = 8.  This means that the number you're searching for can't appear before array[8], i.e. (target - array[0]).  So you read array[8], which has 13; that means that the target can't appear before array[11].  And so on.  The +/- 1 difference lets you skip ahead in your search, because you know that if array[x] = (target +/- N) that the target number can't appear before array[x + N].

Comment: Saw your answer after I finished mine - iPhone not good for updating answers as they happen...

Comment: This solution isn't optimal and could be improved by taking larger strides and backtracking when necessary (only in an unfavorable scenario).  Searching for *16*, if ``arr[0]=8``, you could test ``arr[13]``.  If it is *8* or less, then you can jump forward by 13 again; otherwise, you need to backtrack to somewhere between ``arr[8]`` and ``arr[13-difference]``.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger - the code you gave, applied to the example you selected, performs  worse. See my comment to your solution.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to look at every number in the list. Say you are looking for `8`, and the first number is `5`. You can safely step 3 since 8 cannot occur in less than three steps. You might consider stepping slightly more - say 6 - since there are probably some -1's, but I don't know if that would be more efficient, since you would not be sure it is the "first" occurrence then. So let's stick with the original:

When you get to the new number you determine what size step to take next - in the above if you had taken a step of 3 you would have found 6, step another 2 (8-6) and you find 6 again, step another 2 and you find 8 - you are there! You know it is the first occurrence since the numbers you skipped could not have been 8. And it only took three steps instead of seven.

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer isn't optimal.  If you're trying to minimize the number of probes (array lookups), you can do better than searching from the beginning and a taking steps as small as `` `target - array[i] ``

Since you're allowed to do random access using indexed lookup, you can make far larger strides.  For example if you looking for *9* in an array that starts with `a[0] = 0`, you could examine `a[16]` to see if it is less-than or equal to *0*.   If not, then none of `a[0 .. 16]` can reach *9*.

Bigger strides give you more information per probe (each probe lets you exclude indicies both to the left and to the right).  This lets you gain twice as much information per probe when to compared to minimum strides when searching from the left.

To demonstrate the advantages of search-from-the-middle over search-from-the-left, here's some working code in written in the Python programming language:

```
def find(arr, value, bias=2):
    # With the bias at 2, new probes are in the middle of the range.
    # Increase the bias to force the search leftwards.
    # A very large bias does the same as searching from left side of the range.
    todo = [(0, len(arr)-1)]  # list of ranges where the value is possible
    while todo:
        low, high = todo.pop()
        if low == high:
            if arr[low] == value: return low
            else: continue
        mid = low + (high - low) // bias
        diff = abs(arr[mid] - value)
        if mid+diff <= high: todo.append([mid + diff, high])
        if mid-diff >= low: todo.append([low, mid - diff])
    raise ValueError('Value is not in the array')
```

Conceptually, what the algorithm is doing is trying to gain the maximum amount of information possible with each probe.  Sometimes, it will get lucky and exclude large ranges all at once; sometimes, it will be unlucky and only be able to exclude a tiny subrange.  Regardless of luck, its exclusion zone will be twice as large as the search-from-the-left approach.

Simple test code:

```
arr = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 7, 8]
for i in range(min(arr), max(arr)+1):
    assert arr.index(i) == find(arr, i)
```

Comment: It may be possible to improve the search by a constant factor, e.g. N/(2t) instead of N/t where t is the target number, but I don't think it's possible to do asymptotically better than linear time - you're always limited to skipping ahead (or backtracking) by a factor of t, so something akin to a binary search wouldn't be possible; in the worst case, all of the values (except perhaps for the last one that you examine) are (t-1) or (t-2), or are (t+1) or (t+2), where in either case you're stuck examining at least N/2 of the array elements

Comment: Pathological example: 0,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0 - your code is worse if searching for 2. So "worst case is no worse than for other algorithms" is false.

Comment: The general idea is that searching-from-the-middle-of-a-range gives twice as much information as searching-from-the-start-of-range.  In a 100 element array, probing ``arr[50]`` gives an exclusion band in *both* directions while probing ``arr[0]`` excludes indicies in one direction only.

Comment: Using the example you are giving, I get the following results for your "bisecting" algorithm vs @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot "step at least" algorithm: order = [find this value, your algorithm took N evaluations, Zim's took M evaluations]: [6 4 3*], [7 4 4], [8 4 4], [9 5 5], [10 3 1*], [11 4 2*], [12 5 2*], [13 5 2*], [14 4 2*]. ZimZam's is always as good or better (*) than yours - so I am still not convinced. There may be a better way, but it's not the one you give with your code.